# How Can I use raw queries using SQLiteAsyncConnection.QueryAsync() to delete a row in MVVM cross?

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I tried with following code but its not working .

```
  public void deleteRow(int index)
            {
               conn.QueryAsync<Bill>("Delete From Bill Where Id ='?'", index);

            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think the only problem is that you use `Id ='?'` when it should be `Id = ?`.
When you use `?` in the query you don't want to have it between`''`